# How to make a number=type input a certain amount of characters?

Tags: html, css

In my HTML document, I need a 5-9 digit number from the user in a input-number box. I've looked it up and none of the possible solutions worked. My current code looks like this:

```
<div class="usernumber">
    <input type="number" input placeholder="Type a 5-9 digit number" style="color:rgb(134, 136, 130)">
</div>
```

I have tried to use the "range" attribute (unwanted effect) , and the "maxlength" attribute is unsupported by number input types.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

`<input type="number" min="10000" max="999999999" step="1" />`

Comment: In as much as this is nice for mouse wheel. One can still input numbers below and above the range with this implementation.

Comment: It will fail HTML5 validation though. It is better UX to allow the user to input what they desire and then correct them at submission. Users will become frustrated if they cannot input what they want.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help. It's a JavaScript solution that clears the value if it has more than 9 or less than 5 digits.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('blur', (event) => {

  var val = event.target.value;
  
  if(val.length < 5 || val.length > 9){
  
       event.target.value = '';
  
  }

});
```

```html
<div class="usernumber">
    <input type="number" input placeholder="Type a 5-9 digit number" style="color:rgb(134, 136, 130)">
</div>
```